# Get all available data - swagger

Tags: php, swagger

I'm using curl from php to fetch all the product data from

http://public.je-apis.com/swagger-ui/#!/menus

GET /menus/{menuId}/productcategories/{categoryId}/products

It returns the product result.

```
JustEat.PublicApi.Site.ResponseData.ProductResult {
Id (integer, optional): Int32,
Name (string, optional): String,
Synonym (string, optional): String, 
Description (string, optional): String,
RestaurantMenuNumber (integer, optional): Int32,
RestaurantMenuNumberCode (string, optional): String,
Price (System.Decimal, optional): Decimal,
HasComboOptions (boolean, optional): Boolean,
HasAccessories (boolean, optional): Boolean,
HasRequiredAccessories (boolean, optional): Boolean,
ComboOptions (array[JustEat.PublicApi.Site.ResponseData.MealOptionResult], 
optional): IEnumerable[JustEat.PublicApi.Site.ResponseData.MealOptionResult],
Accessories (array[JustEat.Core.Model.ProductAccessory], optional): 
IEnumerable[JustEat.Core.Model.ProductAccessory],
ContainsNuts (boolean, optional): Boolean,
IsVegetarian (boolean, optional): Boolean,
IsSpicy (boolean, optional): Boolean,
IsTips (boolean, optional): Boolean, 
RequireOtherProducts (boolean, optional): Boolean
}
```

There's other data options available like this i've listed below as stated on the swagger page, how do i access this extra data?  I.E if a product item has meal options how do i get said meal options.

```
JustEat.Core.Model.MealOption {
ProductChoice (array[JustEat.Core.Model.Product], optional): 
IEnumerable[JustEat.Core.Model.Product],
HasAccessory (boolean, optional): Boolean,
DisplayRank (integer, optional): Int32
}
JustEat.Core.Model.ProductAccessory {
Id (integer, optional): Int32,
Name (string, optional): String,
Cost (System.Decimal[System.Decimal], optional): Decimal, 
Required (boolean, optional): Boolean,
ProductId (integer, optional): Int32,
SelectionId (integer, optional): Int32
}
```

Comment: You should probably ask the developer of this API.

Comment: Yeah it actually turns out the data didn't exist, i suspected something wasn't right.